# C - parse key-value pairs from ASCII file

Tags: c, file, scanf, ascii, key-value

I am trying to write a C function that reads the key-value pairs stored in an ASCII file that looks as follows (the text that indicates to ignore a certain line or part of a line is not in the file, of course: I added it for clarity):

```
[SECTION 1 HEADER - ignore this line]
VAR1             =   'xyz'
VAR2          =   3.0
VARIAB3           =   'blabla'
! COMMENT: ignore this line              VAR7 =      'ABC123'
$---------another line to ignore----------------- 
[SECTION 2 HEADER - ignore me!]
varname8                =        'abcd'
$---------yet another line to ignore-----------
[SECTION HEADER - ignore me]
VARIABLE10 =    4.05101e+05      $ignore from the dollar sign to eol
VARIABLE13 =    7e-06      $ignore from the dollar sign to eol
param_1=123
param_2=321
```

As you can see, not all the lines contain (key,value) pairs I would like to retain. Also, the names of the keys don't always have the same length and the values can be strings or numbers... Moreover, the '=' sign can be preceded and/or followed by zero or more spaces. Finally, comments appearing *after* the key,value pair should be ignored.

I've tried the following code to read from the file and parse the key-value pairs:

```
fh = fopen(filename, "r");
    if(NULL == fh) {
        perror(filename);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("File opened succesfully.\n");
        while(fgets(buffer, 100, fh) != NULL)
        {
            {
                int offset;
                int res = sscanf(buffer, "%s = %s%n", key, value, &offset);
                if(res==2)
                {
                    printf("Found: %s = %s\n", key, value);
                }
            }   
        }
    }
```

which gives the following output, clearly failing at capturing the last two key-value pairs:

```
Filename is: sample.tir
File opened succesfully.
Found: VAR1 = 'xyz'
Found: VAR2 = 3.0
Found: VARIAB3 = 'blabla'
Found: varname8 = 'abcd'
Found: VARIABLE10 = 4.05101e+05
Found: VARIABLE13 = 7e-06
File closed.
```

I believe the problem might be in the format string for sscanf: any ideas?

Comment: I suggest looking into `fscanf`. Something like `%[A-Za-z] = %s`.

Comment: What do you mean by "numbers stay numbers"? If they might be strings, read them as as strings and take it from there.

Comment: @picchiolu  " best way to process such a file," -->  Do not use `fscanf()`.  Read the line with `fgets()` and then parse the _string_.

Comment: ...for example `int res = sscanf(str, "%99s = %99[^\n]", varA, equ, varB);` and then examine `varB`.

Comment: But the numbers *are* strings! It's no waste to read the third item as a string. Once you have that you can look at any `'` enclosures and go from there.

Comment: There are many ways to do this. What have you tried? What was the issue with thst approach?

Comment: Use a parser generator to generate the parsing code for you. You don't want a simple parser for this, because the grammar isn't actually that simple.

Comment: @hyde I tried using fscanf and fgets+sscanf but I couldn't find a way to cope with the different ways the key,value pairs can present themselves in the file.

Comment: You have `key = value` which is reasonably straightforward. Try my [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74330697/c-parse-key-value-pairs-from-ascii-file#comment131224934_74330697) on the string read by `fgets`. Worry about the type of third argument later, after you succeed in separating them. Obviously the length restrictions `99` will be for the actual buffer size -1.

Comment: @picchiolu Edit the question to include your [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), do not post it in the comments.

Comment: @Oka: I've edited the question and added the code I've been trying so far.

Comment: @WeatherVane fgets and sscanf seem to work pretty well, but as you can see from the code and output I added to the question, not all the key-value pairs are captured.

Comment: "File not found." is the canonical example of a useless error message.  (Although, since it's being written to the wrong stream, one could argue that it's not an error message ata ll).  Replace `printf("File not found.");` with `perror(filename);`.  The resulting error message is more informative and written to the correct place.

Comment: @WilliamPursell I'll do it, good catch, thanks.

Comment: That is because `param_1=123` is a single string. This and the next do not have the space delimiters that were originally in the sample text.

Comment: One thing you could do is to check for the existence of `'='` in the string with `strchr` and overwrite it with a space, then don't try to match it in the `sscanf`.

Comment: I edited the comment. The original example had spaces, these two new ones do not. You've added them later. I missed the narrative saying they do not need to be there, but as a I wrote, you can simply overwrite the `'='`  to separate the two parts.

Comment: Again, please refresh comments each time. They get edited. Just focus on a solution.

Comment: @WeatherVane Pardon me for my naivete, but if I replace '=' with a space, how am I going to parse the key-value pair afterwards? Would you mind providing some sample code to illustrate your idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you check for and overwrite the `'='` character, to separate the key and value. Perhaps like this snippet

```
char *ptr = strchr(buffer, '=');        // find the '='
if(ptr == NULL)
    continue;
*ptr = ' ';                             // replace with a space
int res = sscanf(buffer, "%s%s", key, value);
if(res != 2)
    continue;
printf("Found: %s = %s\n", key, value);
```

Output

```
Found: VAR1 = 'xyz'
Found: VAR2 = 3.0
Found: VARIAB3 = 'blabla'
Found: varname8 = 'abcd'
Found: VARIABLE10 = 4.05101e+05
Found: VARIABLE13 = 7e-06
Found: param_1 = 123
Found: param_2 = 321
```

Comment: This answer does capture the last two key-value pairs, but fails as it parses the key-value pair on the line that starts with "! COMMENT", which is to be ignored altogether. How come you don't get "Found: ! = COMMENT:" in your output?

Comment: Oh heaven sake. I left out that to keep it simple. Just filter the comment line first. Your code is incomplete, and so is this snippet. It is to illustrate removing the `'='` as you asked, not a complete solution.

Comment: `if(buffer[0] == '!' || buffer[0] == '[' || buffer[0] == '$') continue;`

Comment: Sorry, I thought your code snippet was meant to be plugged in my example "as-is".